# Complete system hang on umount and `ls /dev/sd*`

Tags: gentoo, external-hdd

I have a portable hard drive which I mount on `/mnt/ext`. Normally it works fine. But if I leave it mounted with no activity for sufficiently long, it can cause my system to completely hang. This has happened twice so far. No mouse movement, the clock doesn't update, ctrl-alt-f1 doesn't work. (I don't have a sysrq key to try magic sysrq with.) When I left the house this morning it had been like that for over ten minutes; last time I rebooted after probably five minutes or so. (Update: it was still frozen when I got home after almost ten hours.)

Last time, I'm pretty sure the hang happened when I ran `ls /dev/sd*` (or possibly with `-l`). This seems really odd to me, so it's possible I'm misremembering. This morning I ran `ls /dev/sd*` and it didn't hang, but it did hang when I ran `umount /mnt/ext`. Actually, first time I tried to umount, it complained that the device was busy; I quit the shell that was cd'd inside it, tried to umount again, and then it hung. In both cases, the command running didn't run to completion (I didn't get another shell prompt) or produce any output.

This is a fairly new laptop, but old hard drive. I didn't have this problem on my old laptop with the same hard drive. I don't recall being in this situation with the new laptop and it not crashing, but that doesn't necessarily mean I haven't been. I haven't tried other hard drives.

The hard drive spins down some minutes of inactivity, but it takes longer than that for this problem to kick in. I don't recall ever testing periods between 'a few hours' and 'a few days'.

I'm using gentoo's genkernel, I don't recall which version but I only installed it a few months ago.

This seems to be the relevant section from my system logs: http://pastebin.com/gi8NUp0D. 08:44 is when my system froze; the next entry is from 18:26, when I booted it up again.

Comment: Have you observed it on another computer? Have you had problems if you boot another OS on the same computer? Do run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: I didn't have this problem with the same hard drive on my old laptop. I haven't tried another OS on this one, that would be a time-consuming test but it seems worth trying. Memory problems seem implausible to me, but I'll run memtest at some point.

Comment: @philh the sysrq key is the same key as "print screen" on most keyboards.  If you have that key you can give the magic sysrq a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like disk failure.  When a hard drive begins to fail, or contains unreadable (bad) blocks, trying to read from it will sometimes lead to a serious problem.  In the case of bad blocks, it is whenever a file which includes those blocks is read.

The serious problem is that hardware I/O is uninterruptible for technical reasons, meaning, if that hardware is broken, reads from it may result in the calling process going into an "uninterruptible sleep",<sup>1</sup> and this locks the kernel up, which is why your system freezes.

You should be able to find evidence of this in your system logs.

If the problem is simply bad blocks, you may be able to fix it, at least temporarily, by running `e2fsck -cy` on the partitions (see the `man` page about these switches).  Since this requires reading from the disk, it will cause the same lockup at certain points, so you may need to leave it to run for a long time (possibly, hours, or overnight).  This is not a guaranteed solution, but it will work for some problems.  If you find it still running in the morning, I would give up -- the problem is possibly more serious than just random bad blocks.

---

Another possibility, since your logs of the I/O errors start with `usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 3` is that something wrong is happening with the kernel USB drivers; this would be consistent with the issue beginning specifically on the new laptop. It seems similar to [this problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=136424), which was apparently fixed by removing ehci support from the kernel; if that's modular, you could try this by blacklisting the module or temporarily moving it out of `/lib/modules`; the module is `ehci-hcd` (then run `depmod`, then reboot).  You may also want to [consult this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UHCI#USB) and consider if your kernel is misconfigured.   I don't think it would work at all with an OHCI driver in place of a UHCI one or vice versa, but I don't know, and the same goes for the difference between EHCI and the new XHCI.  Find out exactly what your hardware is (that may not be easy, you'll probably have to reference the manufacturer's spec sheet for the laptop, then lookup the usb controller) and which kernel drivers you are running, then search for bugs in those drivers for your kernel version.

---

<sup>1. These show up in `top` and `ps` output with a **`D`** state.</sup>

Comment: Disk failure sounds plausible, I think I've wondered about it before. I'll give this a go, thanks. Couple of questions- if reading a bad block makes the kernel hang permanently (but maybe I'll discover it's not permanent when I get home), will e2fsck be able to complete at all? And if reading from the disk is what causes problems, does that make sense if I'm right that `ls /dev/sd*` caused a hang? (`ls -l` would stat the device, but I don't think it would read?)

Comment: The hang isn't necessarily permanent, perhaps it depends on the nature of the underlying problem -- I don't know the details, but I've been through it.   If it is broken hardware, it is interesting if `ls /dev/sd*` triggered the problem...I would have thought that is information cached by the kernel.

Comment: `ls /dev/sd*` wouldn't access the disk. It only accesses `/dev` which is in RAM (or swap, but that's unlikely). Of course it could be a coincidence.

Comment: `e2fsck` didn't find any bad blocks. :( I'm now running with `-ccyv` in case it's a write-only problem.

Comment: Looking at my log file (http://pastebin.com/gi8NUp0D), I got I/O errors just before freezing. I don't know if those are a symptom or the cause though.

Comment: They're amost certainly the cause of the lock-up.  As to what caused them, the fact that `e2fsck` ran without errors now means it is not bad blocks; you wrote that this seems to happen only after the drive has been plugged in and idle for some time.  Perhaps something is going wrong *sometimes* when it spins up again, including the USB controller...interesting those logs start with `usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 3` -- I've added a paragraph above about this.